# Distance of closest neighbor points in a vectorspace ${\mathbb R}^n$ (infinitesimal or zero)?

Tags: coloring, infinitesimals

The title should be almost entirely self explaining, but let me give the specific context and use case I'm thinking about while asking too, it's related to the HadwigerNelson problem and chromatic numbers.

For simplicity take ${\mathbb R}^1$, that is simply a line of real numbers. Now take 2 points at unit distance which are connected, $a=0$ and $a'=1$, then $a$ and $a'$ now strictly need to have different colors.
Now add $b$ and $b'$ to the line, these points are the next closest minimum distance points to $a$ and $a'$ (let's assume to their right/in the positive direction).
Is their distance...

...strictly 0, which would mean that $a$ and $b$ effectively share the same coordinate. In turn this would also mean that both $a$ and $b$ are connected to both $a'$ and $b'$. Assuming $a$ and $b$ have different colors the coordinate 0 would essentially be duochrome, meaning $a'$ and $b'$ would need different colors than those used by $a$ and $b$. This would mean that coloring ${\mathbb R}^1$ with discrete 0-dimensional objects (points) requires an infinite amount of colors.

or

...an infinitesimal, in which case the coordinate of $b$ would be $0+infinitesimal$. $a$ would strictly only be connected to $a'$, and $b$ only to $b'$. This would mean a 2-coloring of ${\mathbb R}^1$ is possible using only discrete alternating 0-dimensional objects (points).

Comment: "these points are the next closest minimum distance to points $a$ and $a'$". This is your problem, there is no closest minimum distance, unless of course you take $b=a$ and $b'=a'$.

Comment: While I'm sort of aware of that, I'm asking coming from a point of establishing rules for colorings. Without any way to define "the next point/object", such a coloring should be strictly impossible, meaning ${\mathbb R}^n$ can only be colored with a finite amount of colors when n-dimensional objects are used.

That would be the essence of my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you at all. You should really work on better explaining what you mean; definitions are likely a good place to start.

Comment: Let me try again.
Take the unit distance graph of any vector space ${\mathbb R}^n$ where n>1. No points at unit distance can share the same color. It shouldn't be possible to use objects with less than n dimensions to achieve a valid space filling tesselation of ${\mathbb R}^n$ that uses a finite amount of colors. Filling a plane only with colored lines results in needing infinitely many colors.
That should be proven by the answers in this post.
True?

Comment: "It shouldn't be possible to use objects with less than $n$ dimensions to achieve a valid space filling tesselation of \mathbb R^n$ that uses a finite amount of colors." I am not sure about this. " Filling a plane only with colored lines results in needing infinitely many colors." I am also not sure about this.

Comment: Still I appreciate the attempt so thanks. I'll think this over again, primarily how to get my point across more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of thinking suggests that you consider that $\Bbb R$ is well ordered. It is not.

In $\Bbb Z$, the number just after $1$ is $2$. In $\Bbb R$, or even in $\Bbb Q$, the number just after $1$ simply does not exist. Asking what is the nearest number from $1$ is as absurd as asking what is the greatest integer.

Think at a number $1+x$ just a bit greater than $1$. Then the arithmetic mean of this number and $1$ (that is, $1+\frac x2$) is between $1$ and $1+x$. Just like no greatest integer exists because if $n$ is a very big integer, $n+1$ is even bigger.

Comment: Indeed, which gives a problem of "resolution" of sorts when attemtping to use anything but n-dimensional objects for ${\mathbb R}^n$, which then should mean no solid set of rules for a less than n-dimensional coloring should even be possible.
Wouldn't that mean the only valid colorings for ${\mathbb R}^n$ have to be n-dimensional in nature?

Comment: What do you mean by dimension of a 'coloring'?

Comment: Take for instance the regular hexagonal tiling of ${\mathbb R}^2$ with 7 colors that is proven to work. It uses 2-dimensional objects (hexagons) to achieve a space filling tesselation of ${\mathbb R}^2$, and as such this is a 2-dimensional coloring. Feel free to correct me on the terminology if need be.

By both the way I understood it, and the answer above, any set of rules for a coloring that relies on less than n-dimensional objects requires an infinite amount of colors, such as trying to color ${\mathbb R}^2$ only with discrete 1-dimensional objects (lines).

Comment: I am admittedly not an expert on colorings but this seems to admit an awful lot about general colorings (like periodicity).

Comment: Moreover, I'm not quite sure how the answer above has anything to do with this. The fact that there is no 'closest positive real number' to $0$ does not seem to be related, and in fact it's easy to see that two colors suffice for $\mathbb R^1$: simply alternate colors on intervals of the form $[k,k+1)$.